# Asp.Net Ajax: How to stay on the same page without loosing dynamically added controls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have cshtml page. On the page i have `Details` `<div>` tag. I am populating this div tag by making ajax queries and appending partial view inside this div tag. This is working fine.

Then im submitting the whole form using ajax helper. On the server if model state is invalid then i want to stay on the same page so error message can be shown on the page. However doing so removes any html that was added inside div tag.

**cshtml**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Campaign", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{       
 *** some html here ****


<button class="btn btn-default" id="AddNewRow" type="button">Add New Row</button>
<div id="Details"></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}
```

**Javascript**

```
 $("#AddNewRow").click(function () { 
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            url: someurl
        }).success(function (partialView) {
            $("#Details").append(partialView);
        });        
  });
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CampaignVM model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //What should i return here so error will show on the same page and also keeps the rows i added using ajax
            //if i do 'return View("Create",model)' then all the details row i created using ajax query gets removed
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what ajax is. It always stays in the same page and never redirects (having a `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` is pointless if you were making an ajax call). You have not even specified any `AjaxOptions` (e.g. for the target ID to be updated) so its unclear what the point of it is. If your redirecting its because you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` and therefore are making a normal submit.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the model for this page, include a list of whatever the partial model is. `List<MyPartialModel>` or whatever.

In the main view, when the page is rendered, loop over any `MyPartialModel` in the collection and render them.

This will mean that all of the partial models that get passed back when the ModelState isn't valid get rendered again.

You have to be careful with naming though. If your `MyPartialModel` has a property `Telephone` (for example) then each item in the collection will be named `MyPartialModel[0].Telephone` `MyPartialModel[1].Telephone` etc. This needs to be done when adding the partial to the view in the first place (IIRC), so that the Model Binder knows that they're part of a collection.

I might be slightly out with the syntax (typing from memory), but that's the basic idea.

Regarding what you should do in your controller if the ModelState isn't valid - just return the view using `return View()`. All of the form data that was submitted is stored in the `ModelState` and will be returned to the view automatically, it's just up to you to render it again (by looping over the collection).